# Resizing Material-UI <TextField> causes cursor to exit its container

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

I have been trying to resize material-ui's `<TextField>` component to fit a dynamic container. However doing so causes the cursor input to be allowed leave the textarea altogether (see image #2 / #3 below). Additionally, when there is no text inputted, the cursor begins in a centered position relative to its container's height (see image #1 below).

[image: Image 1] 
[image: Image 2]
[image: Image 2 (with borders)]

The following is a basic example of this in action.

```
const TextArea = () =>
{
  const containerStyle = {
    width: 200,
    height: 200
  }

  const textFieldStyle = {
    marginTop: 8,
    width: '100%',
    height: 'calc(100% - 8px)'
  }

  const inputStyle = {
    width: '100%',
    height: '100%',
    overflowY: 'auto' // tried this afterwards to no avail
  }

  const props = {
    style: textFieldStyle,
    label: 'Workings',
    multiline: true,
    variant: 'outlined',
    InputProps: {style: inputStyle}
  }

  return (
    <div style={containerStyle}>
      <TextField {...props}/>
    </div>
  );
}
```

I would like to know how to resize `<TextField>` to fill a container, while preserving its expected functionality.

**Edit:** I'm using `@material-ui/core v3.6.0` and `react v16.4.1`

**Edit:** [Here is a CodeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/l9kvp498oq) showing the issue.

Comment: Can you state what testing you have done so far.
For instance: you state you get the bug when you resize the textfield, What I am interested in, is to see if you have been able to replicate the same problem on another machine using a different operating system and browser, as this may not be an issue with your coding but rather a browser bug, in which case there is little you can do about it.

Comment: The behaviour is consistent across firefox, chrome, and edge

Comment: Now that you have edited your question and provided visuals we can see its elements that have been styled to in a particular way, and this is likely to be a bug in your CSS or CSS library/extention, can you provide all code

CSS
HTML
JS
ReactJS

so that we can then help identify the bug, thanks
I would also add a border around the textarea in your CSS to visually see the textbox, it could be a width issue

Comment: The code and visuals I have produced are from a basic tester app. There is no extra CSS or HTML other than what I provided. The only other JS/React code is the basic setup (`ReactDOM.render()`) which renders `<TextArea>` in a single div (`width: 100%, height: 100%` relative to the page). Are you saying you can't produce this behaviour?

Comment: Can you add to the textFieldStyle some CSS to display the border please and to container style, one being red border 1px in width and the other being navy in 1px width, this will help us see the invisible boundaries shown

Comment: I've added an image with the requested borders for you. But tbh, this is not something you'll be able to resolve with images alone. It will require creating the `material-ui` component yourself with the same styles I've applied to it, and checking the underlying elements from there.

Comment: I totally agree with you, sadly I dont have a test environment, this is why I am trying to problem solve this way, granted it is not the most effective way, but at present I believe I am the only person trying to help you :)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/187328/discussion-between-sookie-and-datacure).

Comment: @DataCure I just added a CodeSandbox to the question that you can use to see the issue and experiment with solutions.

Comment: Much appreciated @RyanCogswell

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The main issue is that you are not specifying the `rows` property.

> rows  Number of rows to display when multiline option is set to true ([docs](https://material-ui.com/api/text-field/#props)).

The default behavior for the multiline TextField is for it to start out with one line and grow as needed (thus eventually growing outside the bounds of your container height). You can specify `maxRows` to put a limit on this auto-grow behavior, or you can have the number of rows be fixed (scroll bar appears if you try to enter more rows) by specifying the `rows` property.

You can either try to calculate the value for `rows` based on the container height:

```
  const props = {
    style: textFieldStyle,
    label: "derive rows from height",
    multiline: true,
    variant: "outlined",
    rows: containerStyle.height / 21,
    InputProps: { style: inputStyle }
  };
```

I make no promises on the math being robust for different sizes, but dividing by 21 seemed to work in this case.

The other approach is to remove the explicit heights and allow the `rows` property on the `TextField` to control all the other heights:

```
  const props = {
    style: textFieldStyle, // style would not control height
    label: "no explicit height",
    multiline: true,
    variant: "outlined",
    rows: 9,
    InputProps: { style: inputStyle }  // style would not control height
  };
```

When you mention wanting to fill the height of a dynamic container, I'm not sure what is driving the dynamic nature, but if possible I would avoid changing the height of the container dynamically and instead dynamically change the number of rows on the textarea (i.e. use the second approach).

Here's a sandbox showing both approaches:

[image: Edit v0zx4p68ol]

Comment: What's driving the dynamic height behaviour is the inclusion of a fixed-sized calculator below the textarea. In the event that the window height changes, the textarea would need to shrink/grow to fit any remaining available space. I was hoping there would be a solution that didn't require calculating number of rows, but looking at the underlying dom elements, it seems to be the only logical solution. It's a pity material-ui didn't anticipate growing textareas (which I would've thought would be a common occurrence).